Prawn Gem - Print the textbox section dynamically after a table
I use prawn gem to generate a pdf file with tables and other sections. The text_box position are static and it is working as expected. Now I want the text_box below the table to be dynamic. Below is the part of the code I am using,
         view.text_box('Notes', at: [1, 575], width: 600, style: :bold)

          view.table(table_data, contact_section_options) do |table|
            table.row(0).border_width = 0
            table.row(0).style(size: 11, font_style: :bold)
          end

      view.text_box('Service Instructions', at: [1, 225], width: 600, style: :bold)

Here the table data is now dynamic and hence I can't set a constant position for service Instructions because it is overlapping with the above table. Is there a way we can find the bottom position of the above table and set the  service Instructions position as dynamic.

I would do a move_down under the table, or subtract lineheight from cursor for the location.  e.g.
  view.text_box('Notes', at: [1, 575], width: 600, style: :bold)

      view.table(table_data, contact_section_options) do |table|
        table.row(0).border_width = 0
        table.row(0).style(size: 11, font_style: :bold)
      end

  view.move_down 12 # this should be set to whatever the standard lineheight is for your doc

  view.text_box('Service Instructions', at: [1, cursor], width: 600, style: :bold)

More info on using cursor here: https://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf#page=6
Just keep in mind that because prawn draws these pdfs from bottom to the top, be careful of mix-and-matching move_down with at positions.  For instance:
text_box "first cursor at: #{cursor}", at: [35, cursor]
text_box "second cursor at: #{cursor - 12}", at: [35, cursor - 12]
text_box "third cursor at: #{cursor - 24}", at: [35,  cursor - 24]

creates

But that means you will need to keep track of the current position throughout your document which can get tricky.  It might easier to just use move_down, which automatically resets the cursor, which visually produces the same result.
text_box "first cursor at: #{cursor}", at: [35, cursor]
move_down 12
text_box "second cursor at: #{cursor}", at: [35, cursor]
move_down 12
text_box "third cursor at: #{cursor}", at: [35,  cursor]

